# What Ruby on Rails code for this SQL Query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server-2005, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm noob in Ruby on Rails. I have a query here that will show what room/ammenity is available. It did work in C# programming but i don't know how to implement this in Ruby on Rails.

```
Select distinct A.id, A.a_name From Amenities A
    Where A.id not in 
    (
    Select Aa.id From Amenities Aa, Amenity_List AL Where 
    A.id = AL.amenities_id AND 
        (
            (params[:start_date] BETWEEN AL.checkin AND AL.checkout) OR 
            (params[:end_date] BETWEEN Al.checkin AND AL.checkout)
        )
    )
Order by A.id
```

HELP. Thanks! :)

HERE are my models:

```
class Amenity < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :amenity_lists
   has_many :line_items
end

class AmenityList < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :transaction
  belongs_to :amenity

  scope :range, where(:checkin => (params[:start_date])..(params[:end_date]) || :checkout => (params[:start_date])..(params[:end_date]) )

  scope :available, find_by_sql(["Select DISTINCT amenities.id, amenities.a_name" +
                "where amenities.id NOT IN (Select amenities.id from amenities, amenity_lists where amenity.id = amenity_list.amenities_id AND ?)", :range])
```

end

i code it like this. but it didn't work. i am trying to display the all the available amenities given by the start_date and end_date.

here's the log:

```
 c:/Sites/fourk/app/models/amenity_list.rb:6: 
 syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting ')' ...ams[:end_date]) || :checkout => (params[:start_date])..(para... ... ^ c:/Sites/fourk/app/models/amenity_list.rb:6: 
 syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
```

Comment: Rather than give us some sql and saying "translate this into rails please", it's much better if you describe what you actually want to do.  Eg a brief description of the relationships between the relevant models and the results you want to get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I assume you want to find the amenities that are available --- those that are not booked.

I would suggest to use a `named_scope` rather than `scope` and to also move its definition to the `Amenity` class as you want to find the available amenities.

A possible solution is to use a named scope with an embedded sql query:

```
class Amenity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :amenity_lists

  named_scope :available, lambda {
    |start_date, end_date| { 
      :select => 'amenities.*',
      :order => 'id',
      :conditions => ["
        amenities.id NOT IN 
        (
          SELECT aa.id from amenities aa, amenity_lists al WHERE
          amenities.id = al.amenity_id AND
          (
            (? BETWEEN al.checkin AND al.checkout) OR
            (? BETWEEN al.checkin AND al.checkout)
          )
        )", 
        start_date, 
        end_date
      ] 
    }
  }
end
```

Just note that in Ruby, strings can span multiple lines.

Now you can use the given named scope like this:

```
start_date = ...
end_date = ...
available_amenities = Amenity.available(start_date, end_date)
```

This produces the following SQL query:

```
SELECT amenities.* FROM "amenities" 
WHERE (
 amenities.id NOT IN 
 (
  SELECT aa.id from amenities aa, amenity_lists al 
  WHERE
   amenities.id = al.amenity_id AND
   (
    ('2011-05-10 23:57:09' BETWEEN al.checkin AND al.checkout) OR
    ('2011-05-10 23:57:09' BETWEEN al.checkin AND al.checkout)
   )
 )
) ORDER BY id
```

Also, if you are new to the world of Rails, I highly recommend you to watch Ryan Bates' [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) series. Episode 108 is about `named_scope`s. After watching that one, be patient, and start from episode 1. :)

Comment: here's the log------ c:/Sites/fourk/app/models/amenity_list.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting ')'
...ams[:end_date]) || :checkout => (params[:start_date])..(para...
...                               ^
c:/Sites/fourk/app/models/amenity_list.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end

Comment: Could you please append the log to the bottom of the question?